# retrieve older version of OSM object (way)

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

in the OSM api I can get information for a way doing this:

```
/api/0.6/way/#id
```

I'd like to know how that way changed during time, for instance I'd like to know when the way changed name, etc.. This is interesting to study the evolution of territory..

There is a version="" property on the way, but how can I get older versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [LINK](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#History%3a_GET_.2Fapi.2F0.6.2F.5Bnode.7Cway.7Crelation.5D.2F.23id.2Fhistory)

You can get the history of a given element by this:

```
GET /api/0.6/[node|way|relation]/#id/history
```